# Does Ubuntu 11.04 recognize and work easily on a tablet?

Tags: 11.04, tablet

I want to buy a tablet PC and I've seen a new Dell with Ubuntu 11.04 working perfectly.
If I want to install Ubuntu 11.04, will it work easily?

How's the process to install Ubuntu with tablet definitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it would be nice to have the tablet specs of the laptop that you are talking about.

However, I have experienced nice results when installing previous versions of Ubuntu (9.04, 9.10, 10.04, etc.) when installing to an HP Pavilion tx1000, whose characteristics can be reached by [clicking here](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/product?product=3185028&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&lang=en&tmp_track_link=ot_we/prodlink/en_us/3185028/loc:0&cc=us).

[image]

In those experiences, everything in the tablet started working right out off the box.

Unfortunately I can't say for Dell or other brands but although everything may work with no hassle at all, you can experience some issues when trying to calibrate the tablet, or even more when trying to use the on-screen keyboard, which was for me the hardest issue that I had to face with the tx1000.

The procedure for installing in a Tablet Laptop is exactly the same as for a desktop or common laptop, but if your tablet brand or make are different than those that I have mentioned over here, you should look for a different answer. Sorry if so.

Good luck!